# How to prepend data to tableview or collectionview using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, rx-swift

I can see that I can use `Subject` like `Publish` or `Variable` to add new element to table view or collection view and that will show properly at the end but what if need to add new data at the beginning of the table view. what to do then??

How can I prepend data to a observable sequence so that new data shows at the top of tableview or collection view ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest`operator.

Initially, `newData` is an empty array, and when you add data to it, it is displayed at the top of `tableView`

```
    let data = [
        "A New Hope",
        "The Empire Strikes Back",
        "Return of the Jedi"
    ]

    let obsData = Observable.just(data)

    let newData = [
        "The Phantom Menace",
        "Attack of the Clones",
        "Revenge of the Sith"
    ]
    let obsNewData = Observable.just(newData)

    let items = Observable.combineLatest(obsData, obsNewData){
        $1+$0 
    }     

    items.bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (row, film, cell) in
        cell.textLabel?.text = film
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: how does it prepend data?

Comment: With `merge`operator. Please check the new answer.

Comment: getting error `No 'items' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '(Observable<String>) -> (_) -> _'`

Comment: i tried `let items = Observable.of(Observable.just(newData), Observable.just(data)).merge()`  now code compiles but i only get value of `data` array

Comment: Yes! The correct operator is `combineLatest`. And the Observables are created with `just`, as you said. Could you please check the new answer? ;-)

Comment: before updating/binding the table with new data I need to nil the dataSource by using mytableView.dataSource = nil. Otherwise i get (the feature is already delegated to somewhere else ). Please update the answer

Answer (score 0):

A complete look of what i was looking for

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

struct Person {
    let name : String
    let age : Int

}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let personArray = [
        Person(name: "name1", age: 11),
        Person(name: "name2", age: 12),
        Person(name: "name3", age: 13)
    ]

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var items : Observable<[Person]>!

    @IBOutlet weak var mytable: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        items = Observable.just(personArray)
        bindData()
    }

    @IBAction func prependButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let newPersonArray = [
            Person(name: "name -3", age: 11),
            Person(name: "name -4", age: 12)
        ]
        prependData(dataToPrepend: newPersonArray)
    }

    @IBAction func appendButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let newPersonArray = [
            Person(name: "name 6", age: 11),
            Person(name: "name 7", age: 12)
        ]
        appendData(dataToAppend : newPersonArray)
    }



    private func bindData() {
        mytable.dataSource = nil
        items.bindTo(mytable.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell")) { (row, person, cell) in
            if let cellToUse = cell as? TableViewCell {
                cellToUse.label1.text = person.name
                cellToUse.label2.text = "\(person.age)"
            }
        }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }

    private func prependData(dataToPrepend : [Person]) {
        let newObserver = Observable.just(dataToPrepend)
        items = Observable.combineLatest(items, newObserver) {
            $1+$0
        }
        bindData()
    }


    private func appendData(dataToAppend : [Person]) {
        let newObserver = Observable.just(dataToAppend)
        items = Observable.combineLatest(items, newObserver) {
            $0+$1
        }
        bindData()
    }
}
```